# Jtable RowSorter Icon

Tags: java, swing, icons, jtable, tablerowsorter

I have an JTable which is using RowSorter(Java 1.6) and I am using the look and feel which was implemented using Java 1.4, when RowSorter was not added in Java. Now my problem is: when I click on the table header, table gets sorted but the RosSorter icon does not appear on the Table header. I need that icon somehow and I can not upgrade the existing look and feel. Any help ?

Comment: post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about JFrame with JTable (with hardcoded value) inside JScrollPane, there are a few users that can to compile in JDK1.4.xxx

Comment: Basically, you'll need to patch the renderer for the header which shows the icon.

Comment: *"am using the look and feel which was implemented using Java 1.4"*  Are you referring to a publicly available 3rd party PLAF?  Which PLAF is it?

Comment: @kleopatra : How to do that...please explain.....

Comment: @Andrew: I am doing internship in an organization and the jar which contains the look and feel class is private property of the organization.

Comment: OK - so the code of this PLAF is available to you?  I think @kleopatra mention of a 'patch' was presuming you did not have access to the code.  It just needs (is overdue) to be updated.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: Rather than update the look and feel class, another class with a more updated look and feel should be created.  That way, the organization can update their Swing GUIs at their own glacial pace.

Comment: No I dont have access to that code. @Gilbert: plz explain, how can I do that? Can I use Java's Default look and feel only for the table header separately?

Comment: @user2018023: Your organization won't let you read their look and feel class?  Basically, you're going to have to create your own look and feel class that does the same thing as (copies) the organization's look and feel class, but compiled on Java 1.6 or higher.

Comment: @Gilbert: I got ur point, but don't I have any other option?

Comment: Ok, can anybody tell me how can I implement rowsorter with the icon in my code, without using Java's Rowsorter class?

Comment: repeating: it's not the rowsorter it's the _renderer_ you have to make aware of a column's "sorted" property (however that manifests itself in your custom sorting support) - simply let it paint the appropriate icon depending on that property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic approach is to wrap the renderer that is supplied by the LAF, let it configure the rendering component and additionally make it paint a sort icon as appropriate. Something like:

```
final TableCellRenderer r = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
TableCellRenderer wrapper = new TableCellRenderer() {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
            Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int column) {
        Component comp = r.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, 
            hasFocus, row, column);
        if (comp instanceof JLabel) {
            JLabel label = (JLabel) comp;
            label.setIcon(getSortIcon(table, column));
        }
        return comp;
    }

    /**
     * Implements the logic to choose the appropriate icon.
     */
    private Icon getSortIcon(JTable table, int column) {
        SortOrder sortOrder = getColumnSortOrder(table, column);
        if (SortOrder.UNSORTED == sortOrder) {
            return null;
        }
        return SortOrder.ASCENDING == sortOrder ? ascendingIcon : descendingIcon;
    }

    private SortOrder getColumnSortOrder(JTable table, int column) {
        if (table == null || table.getRowSorter() == null) {
            return SortOrder.UNSORTED;
        }
        List<? extends SortKey> keys = table.getRowSorter().getSortKeys();
        if (keys.size() > 0) {
            SortKey key = keys.get(0);
            if (key.getColumn() == table.convertColumnIndexToModel(column)) {
                return key.getSortOrder();
            }
        }
        return SortOrder.UNSORTED;
    }

};
table.getTableHeader().setDefaultRenderer(wrapper);
```

That's the easiest case, working if the rendering component is-a JLabel and doesn't use its icon property somehow else.

Comment: Just one doubt : in the code, u just set the icon, but how does the icon got replaced or moved?

Comment: glad it worked, woman :-) You might consider upvoting/accepting the answer, just sayin' ... don't understand your second comment: the icon is set to either one of the sort icons or null (aka: replaced by none)