# Change colour of JTable Header Column sorter arrow icons

Tags: java, swing, colors, header, jtable

How do I custom the colours of a `JTable`?

The default arrow icons used to show the sorting direction of a column header in my `JTable` are hard to see since they are the same colour as the background.

[image]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot and some basic code?

Comment: Try googling:  **using the UIManager to change JTable**.

Comment: @Arya added an image

Comment: @DevilsHnd I triued using: UIManager.put("Table.sortIconColor", new ColorUIResource(Color.WHITE)); But that does nothing

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while, however I think this information may be useful to other people in the future, I clarify that I found this solution right [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561946/jtable-rowsorter-icon)  and I adapted it to give you the most complete solution possible, I hope you serve:

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Component;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    import javax.swing.JTable;
    import javax.swing.RowSorter.SortKey;
    import javax.swing.SortOrder;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
    import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
    import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
    import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
    import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

    public class TestTableSortIcon extends JPanel {

      private String[] columnNames
              = {"Country", "Capital", "Population in Millions", "Democracy"};

      private Object[][] data = {
        {"USA", "Washington DC", 280, true},
        {"Canada", "Ottawa", 32, true},
        {"United Kingdom", "London", 60, true},
        {"Germany", "Berlin", 83, true},
        {"France", "Paris", 60, true},
        {"Norway", "Oslo", 4.5, true},
        {"India", "New Delhi", 1046, true}
      };

      ImageIcon ascendingIcon= new ImageIcon("src/icons/ascendingIcon.png");
      ImageIcon descendingIcon= new ImageIcon("src/icons/descendingIcon.png");

      private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
      private JTable table = new JTable(model);

      final TableCellRenderer r = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
      TableCellRenderer wrapper;

      private TableRowSorter<TableModel> rowSorter
              = new TableRowSorter<>(table.getModel());

      public TestTableSortIcon() {
        table.setRowSorter(rowSorter);   
        wrapper = new TableCellRenderer() {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                int row, int column) {
            Component comp = r.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, 
                hasFocus, row, column);
            if (comp instanceof JLabel) {
                JLabel label = (JLabel) comp;
                label.setIcon(getSortIcon(table, column));
            }
            return comp;
        }

        /**
         * Implements the logic to choose the appropriate icon.
         */
        private ImageIcon getSortIcon(JTable table, int column) {
            SortOrder sortOrder = getColumnSortOrder(table, column);
            if (SortOrder.UNSORTED == sortOrder) {
                return null;
            }
            return SortOrder.ASCENDING == sortOrder ? ascendingIcon : descendingIcon;
        }

        private SortOrder getColumnSortOrder(JTable table, int column) {
            if (table == null || table.getRowSorter() == null) {
                return SortOrder.UNSORTED;
            }
            List<? extends SortKey> keys = table.getRowSorter().getSortKeys();
            if (keys.size() > 0) {
                SortKey key = keys.get(0);
                if (key.getColumn() == table.convertColumnIndexToModel(column)) {
                    return key.getSortOrder();
                }
            }
            return SortOrder.UNSORTED;
        }

    };
        table.getTableHeader().setDefaultRenderer(wrapper);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);

      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Row Filter");
            frame.add(new TestTableSortIcon());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
          }

        });
      }
    }
```